# C programming strcmp in if statement not evaluating true

Tags: c

I am a Young Coder who is making a Mini Game Lobby, and it doesn't matter what I do the if statements will are not true, and It loops through 3 times then continues not interacting with the loops. All help is appreciated I am trying to finish to show to my friends. I have looked up strcmp things but I still can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I have been working on this for several days each time restarting from the ground up, this is also my first time using strcmp.

```
   for(i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
    do{
    system("cls");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\tZack's Miraculus MiniGames\n\n\n");
    printf("What Is Your Choice? Rock, Paper or Scissors\n");
    printf("Enter Your Answer Here: ");
    scanf("%s", choice);
    }while (strcmp(choice,Rock) != 0 && strcmp(choice,Paper) != 0 && strcmp(choice,Scissors) != 0);


    do
    {
    computer = (rand() %3) + 1;

    if(computer == 1)
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\t\t\t\t\tZack's Miraculus MiniGames\n\n\n");
        printf("Computer Chose Rock\n");
        char computerString[30] = "Rock";
    }

    else if(computer == 2)
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\t\t\t\t\tZack's Miraculus MiniGames\n\n\n");
        printf("Computer Chose Paper\n");
        char computerString[30] = "Paper";
    }

    else
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\t\t\t\t\tZack's Miraculus MiniGames\n\n\n");
        printf("Computer Chose scissors\n");
        char computerString[30] = "Scissors";
    }
    }while (thing != 0);


    if(strcmp(choice, computerString) == 0)
    {
        printf("It Is A Draw!\n");
        printf("Type Anything To Continue: ");
        scanf("%s", placeHolder);
    }

    else if(strcmp(choice, "Rock") == 0 && strcmp(computerString, "Scissors") == 0)
    {
        printf("Winner, Winner Chicken Dinner!\n");
        score++;
        printf("Type Anything To Continue: ");
        scanf("%s", placeHolder);
    }

    else if(strcmp(choice, "Paper") == 0 && strcmp(computerString, "Rock") == 0)
    {
        printf("Man Will Always Beat Machine! (You Win)\n");
        score++;
        printf("Type Anything To Continue: ");
        scanf("%s", placeHolder);
    }

    else if(strcmp(choice, "Scissors") == 0 && strcmp(computerString, "Paper") == 0)
    {
        printf("You Win!\n");
        score++;
        printf("Type Anything To Continue: ");
        scanf("%s", placeHolder);
    }

    else if(strcmp(choice, "Scissors") == 0 && strcmp(computerString, "Rock") == 0)
    {
        printf("Better Luck Next Time, Computer Wins!\n");
        printf("Type Anything To Continue: ");
        scanf("%s", placeHolder);
        computerScore++;
    }

    else if(strcmp(choice, "Rock") == 0 && strcmp(computerString, "Paper") == 0)
    {
        printf("Computer Beats %s\n", name);
        printf("Type Anything To Continue: ");
        scanf("%s", placeHolder);
        computerScore++;
    }

    else if(strcmp(choice, "Paper") == 0 && strcmp(computerString, "Scissors") == 0){
        printf("Computer Prevails!\n");
        printf("Type Anything To Continue: ");
        scanf("%s", placeHolder);
        computerScore++;
    }

    }

    printf("The Final Score Is %s %d and Computer %d", name, score, computerScore);

}
```

Comment: Without the full code and with the ugly indent it's hard to say, but did you try fixing `strcmp(choice,Rock)` and others to `strcmp(choice,"Rock")`?

Comment: I think so but I will try.

Comment: You should edit to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. See [ask].

Comment: in `strcmp(choice,Rock)`, `strcmp(choice,Paper)`, `strcmp(choice,Scissors)` are `Rock`, `Paper`, and `Scissors` meant to be variable names or string literals?

Comment: One thing to note is that you have, in your if statements, things like `char computerString[30] = "Paper";`. These declare variables that are only visible within that if, as they go out of scope when the if block ends. If you have another variable with the same name declared outside the block, these lines do not update that one. You'd most likely need a call to `strcpy` to do that

Comment: I also have a warning in the code that says, "Warning: unused variable "computerString" "

Comment: thanks so much everyone! and Rock, Paper and Scissors are names with strings attached.

Comment: The warning is as straightforward as it seems, you are just not using the variable, you can remove it and your code will do the exact same thing it's doing now. In fact, your compiler will probably optimize it out anyways. As mentioned by @PhilM, the variable goes out of scope at the end of the `if` statement.

Comment: @ZacharyHunter That warning means that you have declared the variable "coupterString" but are not using it.

Comment: You also have an infinite do-while loop in there.

Comment: This is only a part of a 200 line code it ends later and the do while thing != 0 is declared as 0 earlier, I used it to break up the if statements.

Answer (score 1):

```
            else
            {
                system("cls");
                printf("\t\t\t\t\tZack's Miraculus MiniGames\n\n\n");
                printf("Computer Chose scissors\n");
                char computerString[30] = "Scissors";
            }
            }while (thing != 0);


            if(strcmp(choice, computerString) == 0)
            {
                printf("It Is A Draw!\n");
                printf("Type Anything To Continue: ");
                scanf("%s", placeHolder);
            }
```

The `char computerString[30] = "Scissors";` creates a variable whose scope is the block in which it was created. The following `}` ends that block, so the variable no longer exists. Further down in the code, when you pass `computerString` to `strcmp`, there is no variable with that name in scope.

To fix it, create `computerString` earlier in the code, in a scope that includes all the code that needs to access it. Use `strcpy` to set values for `computerString`.

Your compiler was warning you that you assigned `computerString` a value and then let it go out of scope without using that value.

Comment: I just made some these changes and It is working amazing!

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and created a small sample that fixes a few things for you. It doesn't do everything, but it does show you how to properly compare strings etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char choice[10];
    char *computerChoices[] = {"Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"};
    char *computerChoice = NULL;

    /* Use current time as seed for random generator */
    srand(time(0));     

    do
    {
        printf("\t\t\t\t\tZack's Miraculus MiniGames\n\n\n");
        printf("What Is Your Choice? Rock, Paper or Scissors\n");
        printf("Enter Your Answer Here: ");
        scanf("%s", choice);
    }while (strcmp(choice, computerChoices[0]) != 0 && strcmp(choice, computerChoices[1]) != 0 && strcmp(choice, computerChoices[2]) != 0);

    computerChoice = computerChoices[rand()%3];
    printf("Computer Chose %s\n", computerChoice);

    if(strcmp(choice, computerChoice) == 0)
    {
        printf("It Is A Draw!\n");
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just finished the Rock, Paper, Scissors part and it works amazing thanks to everyone!

Comment: Glad you got it working. If my example helped you at all, please upvote my answer so a get a little reputation. :-)